# Decimal --> Hex Recursively in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have to find a recursive function to convert a decimal number into hexadecimal. So far my code seems to only work partially. I am really really stuck. Can someone help me fix this. Thanks

Here's my code:

```
 recurse :: Int -> [Char]
 recurse n
  |(n <= 15)            =convDecHex(quot n 16)
  |otherwise            =reverse(convDecHex (n `mod` 16) ++ recurse(quot n 16))
```

Comment: slight OT: is there a (online-)course on recursion using Haskell somewhere? I see a lot of questions where the answer must use *recursion* lately

Comment: you are using `mod` and `quot` together which is unusual and might result in errors (mostly on the *negative* side ;) ) - better use `quot` and `rem` *or* `div` and `mod` together: [see here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:quot) - indeed there is are convenience functions for this already: `divMod` and `quotRem`

Comment: I know man, thanks a lot. I modified my base case to just pass n. I just didn't want to post the code, because I don't want others in my class to just be copying my code and using it as their own solutions for the assignment. This has been happening quite often lately with other students and then we run into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first `quot n 16` probably doesn't do what you have in mind. If `n <= 15`, `convDecHex` will already work on `n` because it already has cases for all (positive) values of its argument when it is less than or equal to `15`.

Also, you are reversing it and reversing it back at each step. Instead of doing this, you will want to reverse it only once.

Comment: so how should I modify the base case then?

Comment: (quot n 16) == 0 =convDecHex(n `mod` 16)

Comment: @RumenHristov Think of it this way: if you run `encodeHex 14`, what result will you want? `convDecHex` will automatically work on any value that is `<= 15` (since you have all the cases of that covered in the `convDecHex` definition).

Comment: ok thanks, I figured the recursion. But how should I reverse now? I am not sure where to reverse. Other than that, here's the new recursion: |(n <= 15)         =convDecHex(n)

Comment: The final result needs to be reversed, so you only need to reverse once: at the very end, after the recursive calls have all finished and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference - here is a working example:

```
import Data.Char (intToDigit, toUpper)

toHex :: Int -> String
toHex = map toUpper . reverse . recurse
  where recurse n
          | n < 16    = [ intToDigit n ]
          | otherwise = let (q,r) = n `divMod` 16
                        in (intToDigit r) : recurse q
```

And an example:

```
λ> toHex (16*16*14 + 16*4 + 11)
"E4B"
```